# How to create a debian package from ruby source code?

Tags: ruby, debian, package, fluentd

We are trying to create a debian package from ruby source code. It's for fluentd software. We know that a pre-built debian package for fluentd already exists. But because of the build systems in our ocmpany we have to create a debian package manually.

We did try out deb2gem to create a deb package source but running into issues while building it.

Any pointers about how to build a debian package from scratch - using ruby source code would be helpful.

So here are the steps I followed.

Our work environment - doesn't let outside connections from the production hosts. So I can't just gem install fluentd.

Since it's a debian Wheezy build, I need to build a debian package and install on it. We can't download the binary debian package which fluentd provides and use it - so I have to build it from source.

So, I followed this procedure:

1. Download the actual gem of fluentd from here - https://rubygems.org/gems/fluentd
2. Then use gem2deb tool to create a debian source files/templates. The debian/control file looks like this - http://pastebin.com/CHJXdJMi
3. So when I run debuild -uc -us -b now - technically it should build a .deb package. But I get errors like these - http://pastebin.com/fEYFARRQ
4. The ruby version on the host I am doing is 2.3.1 But I think gem2deb uses ruby 1.9.1. And fluentd needs ruby >=1.9.3 to build it from source.

So this is where I am stuck at. I think if I don't use gem2deb then I have to figure out a way to just checkout the source code of fluentd from git and build a debian package from scratch.

There is not much info about how to go about that anywhere except this - https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Ruby/Packaging

Appreciate any help in advance!

Thanks

Comment: what issues are you running into? Edit your question and add the errors or issues you face.

Comment: On a Debian system you can use dpkg-deb to build a .deb package. Look here also, even though it is Ubuntu specific it is debian based and will usually work the same on other debian distros. http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.htmlhttp://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html